# Bash: write args from back. Can I do this better than N^2?

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $1 == "-r" ]]
then
    arr=()
    i=0
    for var in ${@:2}
    do
        arr[$i]+=$var
        ((i++))
    done
    ((i--))
    for (( j=$i;$j >= 0;j=$j-1 ))
    do
        echo ${arr[$j]}
    done
fi
```

this is my script to wrote args from last to first one if I add `-r`.

Can I do this better?
Because now this is N^2. So I feel like I could do this better but I have no idea how. Any advice?

Comment: Well, I would `printf "%s\n" "$@" | rev`

Comment: well it was that simple. I feel stupid now.

Comment: Unless there are newlines in the arguments.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412894/74329) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just index arguments from the back:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$#;++i)); do
    echo "${@: -$i:1}"
done
```

See `${parameter:offset:length}` expansion in [bash manual shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: ```echo "${@: -$i:1}"``` wow this line it's so useful. Thanks. I didn't know this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the arguments from the last to the second. Use indirection to use the number as the name of the variable:

```
for ((i=$#; i>1; --i)) ; do
    printf '%s\n' "${!i}"
done
```